# Time Complexity of Recursion which has loop in it

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode buildTree(int[] preorder, int[] inorder) {
        return helper(0,0, inorder.length - 1, preorder, inorder);
    }
    public TreeNode helper(int preStart, int inStart, int inEnd, int[] preorder, int[] inorder){
        if(preStart > preorder.length - 1 || inStart > inEnd){
            return null;
        }

        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(preorder[preStart]);

        int inIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <= inEnd; i++){
            if(root.val == inorder[i]){
                inIndex = i;
            }
        }           

        root.left = helper(preStart + 1, inStart, inIndex - 1, preorder, inorder);
        root.right = helper(preStart + inIndex - inStart + 1, inIndex + 1, inEnd, preorder, inorder);

        return root;
    }
}
```

In this case, how do I get time complexity?

I thought it is O(N^2) when N is length of input array because recursive call has a loop in it.
Is it correct?

This is the leetCode question. And I want to make sure what the time complexity is.

Comment: The reasoning is not quite right. `for(i=1; i<=4; i++)` is definitely a loop, it would not bump the complexity from linear to quadratic. It all depends on how many iterations that loop does and what relation than number has to N.

Comment: So, if you wanted the for loop to run the maximum number of times possible, what would the tree described by the input look like? A sort of worst-case scenario.